# Swift Animated Pill Style Notifications

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

iOS 14? introduced a really nice looking pill style notification drop in at the top of the screen, for example when switching the mute Hardware key or when AirPods connect.

[image: Example]

Is this API available anywhere in UIKit or SwiftUI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471684/how-to-show-a-message-balloon-in-swiftui/68472624#68472624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I can confirm there is no available Apple API for this (I imagine there will be in the future).

Answer (score 1):

I think I am too late to the game, but I have created a dependency for this called [PillboxView](https://github.com/Awesomeplayer165/PillboxView) in UIKit since I too could not find any APIs like this. But to answer your question, Apple (alongside others like Windows) has not published an API like this, like they usually do with other things ([FloatingPanel](https://github.com/scenee/FloatingPanel) for instance).

Note: For PillboxView, there is [documentation](https://docs.awesomeplayer.tech/documentation/pillboxview) there to help you along with the code syntax.